# Une traduction de « van onderen », « attention, il y a un objet qui tombe »

Tags: traduction, oral, interjections, néerlandais

J’essaie de trouver une traduction de « van onderen ». On l’utilise parfois pour avertir les gens que quelque chose tombe. Tout dictionnaire donne seulement son sens littéral, à savoir « d’en bas ». Pour éviter des malentendus, j’écrirai le mot néerlandais pour le désigner, et pas sa traduction mot à mot.

Je sais que le mot « attention » est utilisé lorsque les gens aux alentours doivent être vigilants.  La tournure « van onderen » n’est utilisée que quand un objet qui met en danger la vie d'un homme tombe. Une fois le cri poussé, tous ceux qui l'ont entendu savent aussitôt qu’ils doivent regarder vers le haut, et s’éloigner du lieu où cette chose va frapper le sol.

On l’emploie aussi pour la certitude, c’est-à-dire qu’on l'utilise sans savoir si quelqu’un est assez proche pour être touché, autrement dit, le cri ne requiert pas la présence de gens à proximité.

Voici quelques exemples de circonstances dans lesquelles on s'écrie : un arbre au bord d’un chemin qui s’affaisse, un mur qui s’écroule, des tuiles qui sont jetées d’un toit lors une tempête.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attention, chute de pierre

est un panneau routier que l'on place avant les portions de route sur lesquelles peuvent tomber des pierres, surtout par forte pluie, ou tempête.

> Attention ! reculez ! le ** va tomber 
>   Attention ! écartez-vous de ... !
>   Attention ! arrêtez-vous ! le (ou la) ** risque de chuter !

Sont des cris d'alarme pour prévenir quelqu'un dans une des situations mentionnées dans la question.

Pour prévenir quelqu'un qui s'approche d'une zone dangereuse :

> Attention, danger ! Prenez garde à ...

Answer (score 1):

De manière générale on dira *Attention !* en français. Maintenant on peut diriger l'attention des pesonnes visées en ajoutant / pointant une *direction*

> Attention, là haut !
>   Là-bas ! prêt de... !

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une expression spécialement dédiée à mettre en garde une personne concernant la chute d'un objet.

Answer (score 0):

En anglais canadien il y a le fameux "[timber](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8352831) !" qui est spécifique à **un arbre** qui tombe. L'OQLF (Office Québecois de la Langue Française)le traduit officiellement par , et recommande,

> attention !

même si dans les fait les francophones du pays utilisent le mot "timber", comme le constate l'OQLF.

> Historiquement, les chantiers forestiers ont été ouverts au Québec par
>   des entreprises anglophones au cours du 19e siècle et de la première
>   moitié du 20e siècle. Ces compagnies ont pénétré les forêts
>   québécoises avec tout un arsenal de procédures, techniques et
>   équipements nouveaux conçus et présentés en anglais aux travailleurs
>   francophones. Dans ce contexte, la terminologie anglaise s'implanta
>   facilement dans le domaine en remplaçant même des expressions
>   françaises courantes. Ainsi les avertissements Attention! ou Gare à
>   vous! ont-ils cédé le pas dans la langue spontanée des bûcherons à
>   l'interjection anglaise, à éviter,Timber!

Si la traduction que vous cherchez est pour une bande dessinée ou quelque chose d'humoristique vous pourriez utiliser l'expression qui est relativement connue des francophones de par les films mettant en scène des bucherons.

Si c'est pour un texte plus sérieux, il faudra utiliser "Attention !" suivi de quelques mots d'explication.